# How do I use Spring's @Cacheable with Aerospike as the cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aerospike

I just want to use `Aerospike` as the backing cache for `Spring` `CacheManager`.
Should I use spring data aerospike when I don't intend to use `Aerospike` as a data-store but only as a cache?

Is there any implementation available similar to `HazelcastCacheManager` or do I need to write my own?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: found this https://github.com/shaileshmishra008/spring-cache-aerospike project.
If anyone comes here with a similar question.

Comment: as soon as stackoverflow allows, please answer your own question. I assume you commented because you are blocked for now

Comment: yes, posted now, since i am unblocked now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this implementation for Aerospike Cache Manager.

https://github.com/shaileshmishra008/spring-cache-aerospike

I was able to write a version using this project as a reference.

Comment: Are you going to post yours on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

There were some big changes in the Cache area in Spring Data Aerospike - starting from versions 2.5.0/3.0.0.

A Medium article about Caching with Spring Boot and Aerospike:
https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/caching-with-spring-boot-and-aerospike-17b91267d6c