# Aerospike as cache

Tags: spring, caching, aerospike

I am trying to implement **Aerospike** as **cache** in spring boot project. I had not found any implementation and documentation regarding this. I don't have idea of how to implement cache manager. please help if any solution available .

Comment: https://www.aerospike.com/blog/build-restful-web-service-with-spring-boot/

Comment: I want to use aerospike as cache not as database .Can you help over implementing it as cache

Comment: I believe this question may have been answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579772/how-do-i-use-springs-cacheable-with-aerospike-as-the-cache

The only answer given there suggests to use https://github.com/shaileshmishra008/spring-cache-aerospike but I cannot vouch for the quality of that project, not having used it myself.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this old discussion on the Aerospike forum about a simple Cache implementation using Aerospike: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/using-aerospike-as-a-cache-spring-integration-of-aerospike-with-cache-manager/1628

Answer (score 0):

There were some big changes in the Cache area in Spring Data Aerospike - starting from versions 2.5.0/3.0.0.

Check out this medium article about Caching with Spring Boot and Aerospike: https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/caching-with-spring-boot-and-aerospike-17b91267d6c